Dualizing Sheaf of Nodal Curve
Let $C$ be a connected, nodal (I'm working with definition of nodal curves from Alper's notes on Stacks & Moduli, see p 210), projective curve over an alg closed field $k$, beeing everywhere smooth except at a node $z \in C(k)$.
Let $\pi:N \to C$ be its normalization resolving singularity, set $\Sigma:=\{p,q\}=\pi^{-1}(z)$,
and define by $\omega_C \subset \pi_*\Omega_N(\Sigma)$ the subsheaf declaring its sections at open $V \subset C$ to consisting of sections $s$ in $\Omega_N(\Sigma)(\pi^{−1}(V)$ (i.e. with at worst simple poles along $\Sigma$) such that at preimages $p,q$ of the node $z$ (if $z \in U$) we have relation $\text{res}_p(s) + \text{res}_q(s) = 0$.
Question: Exercise 5.2.21(d) in Alper's above linked notes (page 215) asks to show that $\omega_C$ defined that way is indeed the dualizing sheaf, ie that for every coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$, the natural pairing
$$\operatorname{Hom}_{O_C}(\mathcal{F},\omega_C)\times H^1(C,\mathcal{F}) \to H^1(C,\omega_C) \xrightarrow{\text{trace}} k$$
is perfect.
Note that the claim itself is known and there are several ways to do it (see e.g. in Q. Liu's AGeo 10.3.12 or explicit construction in P. Belmans' notes), but both approaches not explicitly follow the strategy proposed in the hint in the adressed exercise to somehow reduce to the case of a smooth curve by considering the normalization and
the concern in this question is to understand how the argumentation via proposed "reduction to smooth case" technique Alper suggested works in detail.
I posed identical question a while ago in MO where I also sketched my up to now failed approaches I applied so far, but it seems maybe that the argumentation can be carried out in simpler way then I thought.

Please keep edits to a minimum.
